# Having error with mongoose and expressjs

Tags: web-applications, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie about node.js and mongodb, i decided to use expressjs framework 
i try to write a web-app by this language, now i meet a trouble about using mongoose
i already install mongodb and mongoose by npm, but in file app.js, when i write:

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
```

==> server can not run,
But when i removed this line `mongoose = require('mongoose');` ==> server run..
Please help me, how to use mongoose in express, or another way to connect express with mongodb

Comment: When you say the server doesn't run, what happens? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: mongoose have install in folder node_modules. i wrote a file server.js, test to use `require('mongoose')`, it doesn't get any problems, but i try to use `require('mongoose')` in file `app.js` of expressjs and got error. ERROR:`The "sys" module is now called "util".It should have a similar interface. node.js:201.throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick.Error:require.paths is removed.Use node_modules folders,or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.at Object. anonymous>(/Users/huy/NEP/node_modules/mongoose/support/node-mongodb-native/lib/mongodb/bson/bson.js:1:70)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `mongoose` installed locally (in the folder node_modules that is on the same level with your server.js file) OR that it's installed globally.

If that's not the case please paste the error message so we can determine exactly what's the root of the problem.

Comment: mongoose have install in folder node_modules. i wrote a file server.js, test to use `require('mongoose')`, it doesn't get any problems, but i try to use `require('mongoose')` in file `app.js` of expressjs and got error. ERROR:`The "sys" module is now called "util".It should have a similar interface. node.js:201.throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick.Error:require.paths is removed.Use node_modules folders,or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.at Object. anonymous>(/Users/huy/NEP/node_modules/mongoose/support/node-mongodb-native/lib/mongodb/bson/bson.js:1:70)`

Comment: What version of Node do you have? And of Mongoose as well?

Comment: node version v0.5.11-pre.
express version 2.5.2.
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
mongoose version 2.4.1

Comment: upgrade to Node 0.6.6, Node 0.5.x is unstable.

Comment: but it's really 0.6.6. i checked it by: `node --version`

Answer (score 0):

Add mongoose to your package.json file as a dependency, then run "npm install" from the shell. Should install mongoose and anything else you need. 
-fs